# Insert Data From One Table to Another Table and Add New Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I have two tables.
Temporary table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temporary` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_bin` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `orderDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;
```

And orders table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_bin` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `orderNumber` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to insert all values of Temporary table to Orders table and add orderNumber manually with this : `uniqid(rand())` .

I have use `INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM temporary WHERE FK_user = ?`
But they don't work because orderNumber don't exist in Temporary table ...

How I can do ? please

Comment: I don't see the problem there. Just specify the columns on the select `INSERT INTO ORDERS(id, FK_user, FK_bin, orderNumer, orderDate) SELECT t.id, t.FK_user, t.FK_bin, UUID() as orderNumber, t.orderDate  from temporary t;`

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *`. mention each column names in both the insert into and select statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping i understand your questioin correctly. I think below query will help.

```
INSERT INTO orders(id , FK_user , FK_bin , orderNumber , orderDate) 
(SELECT id , FK_user , FK_bin , uniqid(rand()) AS orderNumber , orderDate 
 FROM temporary WHERE FK_user = ?);
```

Use your function to generate order number in select statement as mentioned in above query.

Comment: Thank you, it's work, I have a question : the "as" is to connect uniqid variable to orderNumber column ?

Comment: As is used to give alias to value of your function. In this case we are giving alias orderNumber to uniqid(rand()).